# How to add custom checklist plugin in Froala Editor in angular 8?

Tags: plugins, angular8, froala

I've tried to implement custom plugin of checklist using below code, by making custom plugin and assigning it to `FroalaEditor.PLUGINS`, it seems something missing, it shows checklist label that I've assigned in `TEMPLATE` Variable. Then it need to be register in editor and can be used in plugins.

```
(function (FroalaEditor) {

    FroalaEditor.DEFAULTS = Object.assign(FroalaEditor.DEFAULTS, {
        checklist: true
    });
    FroalaEditor.PLUGINS.checklist = function (editor) {
        // Define a unique identifier for the plugin.

        const ID = 'fr-checklist';
        // Define the default options for the plugin.
        const DEFAULTS = {
            itemPrefix: '• ',
            itemSuffix: '\n'
        };

        // Define a template for the plugin.
        const TEMPLATE =
            '<button class="fr-command fr-btn fr-checklist-btn" data-cmd="' +
            ID +
            '" title="Checklist">' +
            '<i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>' +
            '</button>';

        // Define a method to toggle the checklist formatting.
        function toggle() {
            console.log('test toggle', editor.commands);
            editor.commands.toggleClass('fr-checklist', 'fr-checklist-item');
        }

        function toggle1() {
            _attach();
        }

        // Define a method to check if the current selection is in a checklist item.
        function isActive() {
            return editor.el.querySelector('.fr-checklist-item') !== null;
        }

        // Define a method to initialize the plugin.
        function _init() {
            console.log('cheklist iniit');

            editor.events.on(
                'mousedown',
                function () {
                    const checklistItem = editor.el.querySelector('.fr-checklist-item');
                    if (checklistItem && !checklistItem.contains(document.activeElement)) {
                        checklistItem.blur();
                    }
                },
                true
            );
            _attach();
        }

        // Define a method to attach the plugin to the editor.
        function _attach() {
            console.log('cheklist _attach');

            const button = document.createElement('button');
            button.className = 'fr-command fr-btn fr-checklist-btn';
            button.setAttribute('data-cmd', ID);
            button.setAttribute('title', 'Checklist');
            button.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>';
            button.addEventListener('click', toggle);

            // editor.toolbar.get()
            document.querySelector('.fr-btn-grp').appendChild(button);

            editor.events.on('keydown', function (e) {
                if (e.which === FroalaEditor.KEYCODE.ENTER && isActive()) {
                    const el = editor.selection.element();
                    const html = el.innerHTML;
                    if (html === DEFAULTS.itemSuffix) {
                        editor.commands.exec('insertHTML', DEFAULTS.itemSuffix);
                        return false;
                    } else if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'li' && !html) {
                        const newItem = document.createElement('li');
                        newItem.innerHTML = DEFAULTS.itemPrefix;
                        el.parentNode.insertBefore(newItem, el);
                        editor.selection.setBefore(newItem);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });

            editor.events.on('keyup', function (e) {
                if (e.which === FroalaEditor.KEYCODE.BACKSPACE && isActive()) {
                    const el = editor.selection.element();
                    const html = el.innerHTML;
                    if (html === DEFAULTS.itemPrefix) {
                        const prevEl = el.previousSibling;
                        if (prevEl.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'li') {
                            el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
                            editor.selection.setBefore(prevEl);
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        // Return the plugin object.
        return {
            _init: _init,
            _attach: _attach,
            toggle1: toggle1
        };
    };
})(FroalaEditor);

FroalaEditor.DefineIcon('checklist', { NAME: 'star' });
FroalaEditor.RegisterCommand('checklist', {
    title: 'Magic',
    icon: 'fr-checklist'
});
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).